# can't find npm module despite installing it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run the example of `express-fileupload`:

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

// default options
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (Object.keys(req.files).length == 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  sampleFile.mv('/filename.jpg', function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});
  app.listen(2000)
```

despite install the "successfully"  module using :

```
npm install -g express-fileupload
```

I get the following error :

```
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express-fileupload'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SESA476712\Desktop\delete\dragand drop\app-js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

any idea what I'm missing here ? 
thanks in advance!

**1st Update**
**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "draganddrop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Show us your `package.json` file

Comment: Not every package is supposed to be installed globally; `express-fileupload` is supposed to be installed locally, and only installing it globally requires a `link`. Just install it without the `-g` flag and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this ,

```
npm install --save express-fileupload
```

Hope this works .

Comment: thanks. It did, but don't get why ? I'll accept your answer after 5min

Comment: @Engine , please accept the answer whenever you get free , Thank you

Comment: I don't believe `--save` has anything to do with it.  It's a difference of global versus local.

Answer (score 3):

You did what is called a global install, which installs a module at the system level, useful for things like command-line utilities.

Since you are trying to `require` a module,  what you need to do is a local install, which puts the module into `node_modules`, where your application can `require` it.

Instead of

```
npm install -g express-fileupload
```

use

```
npm install express-fileupload --save
```

`-g` was the indicator for global.  Remove that.  I also added on `--save`, which adds `express-fileupload` to your `package.json` `dependencies`, which is important for you to be able to reproduce this configuration later.